# Adding and subtracting values from a column between two data frames

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape, dplyr

I've two dataframes as under:

DF1:

```
+-----+---------+-----+-----+
| ID  | CURRENT | JAN | FEB |
+-----+---------+-----+-----+
| 123 |       2 |   3 |   4 |
| 456 |       1 |   5 |   0 |
+-----+---------+-----+-----+
```

DF2:

```
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+
| ID  | CURRENT_2018    | JAN_2018 | FEB_2018 | UNITS_SWAP |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+
| 123 |               5 |        6 |        7 |         12 |
| 456 |               4 |        8 |        6 |          6 |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

What I'm trying to do here is subtract the number in `UNITS_SWAP` from rows in DF2 sequentially until the number in `UNITS_SWAP` reaches zero.
Also while doing this, add the number of subtracted `UNITS_SWAP` from each row to their respective matching rows in DF1 so that the total of ID's for same months remain the same in both the end result is as under

DF1:

```
+-----+---------+-----+-----+
| ID  | CURRENT | JAN | FEB |
+-----+---------+-----+-----+
| 123 |       7 |   9 |   5 |
| 456 |       5 |   7 |   0 |
+-----+---------+-----+-----+
```

DF2:

```
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| ID  | CURRENT_2018    | JAN_2018 | FEB_2018 |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
| 123 |               0 |        0 |        6 |
| 456 |               4 |        6 |        6 |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+
```

The total by ID and month before aggregating for ID 123

```
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
|  ID   | CURRENT, CURRENT_2018 | JAN, JAN_2018 | FEB, FEB_2018 |
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
| 123   |                     2 |             3 |             4 |
| 123   |                     5 |             6 |             7 |
| TOTAL |                     7 |             9 |            11 |
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

This total should match with the totals after aggregating:

```
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
|  ID   | CURRENT, CURRENT_2018 | JAN, JAN_2018 | FEB, FEB_2018 |
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
| 123   |                     7 |             9 |             5 |
| 123   |                     0 |             0 |             6 |
| TOTAL |                     7 |             9 |            11 |
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Similarly for ID 456

Before:

```
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
|  ID   | CURRENT, CURRENT_2018 | JAN, JAN_2018 | FEB, FEB_2018 |
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
| 456   |                     1 |             5 |             0 |
| 456   |                     4 |             8 |             6 |
| TOTAL |                     5 |            13 |             6 |
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

After:

```
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
|  ID   | CURRENT, CURRENT_2018 | JAN, JAN_2018 | FEB, FEB_2018 |
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
| 456   |                     5 |             7 |             0 |
| 456   |                     0 |             6 |             6 |
| TOTAL |                     5 |            13 |             6 |
+-------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Script to load the data:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(ID = c(123,456), 
                 CURRENT = c(2,1), 
                 JAN = c(3,5),
                 FEB=c(4,0))

DF2 <- data.frame(ID = c(123,456), 
                  CURRENT_2018 = c(4,5), 
                  JAN_2018 = c(6,8),
                  FEB_2018=c(7,6),
                  UNITS_SWAP =c(12,6))
```

Comment: Can you please make it easier for people to help you by sharing the data in a way we can load directly? (See the answers to your recent questions for examples of people doing this for you.)

Comment: @JonSpring just did that
Thanks